# The equivalent windows command to find macaddress

Tags: linux, windows, mac-address

I use the following linux command to find the macaddress

```
"ifconfig | grep enp0s20f6 | awk '{print $5}'"
```

What should be the equivalent windows command to find the macaddress?

I linux, the result of ifconfig is filtered using grep and awk. Is there any way to modify the equivalent windows command to get only the macaddress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows:

```
    C:\>ipconfig /all
    Windows IP Configuration
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : PC-10234
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : mydomain.com

   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mydomain.com
                                       mydomain.com
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-99-88-64-A1-F0

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 73-2B-4F-D5-12-A0

C:\>
```

#### Or

```
C:\>getmac
Physical Address    Transport Name
=============================================================================
2C-3F-45-02-1B-32   \Device\Tcpip_{7E49B486-120A-4BC2-2114-B345A4D5C5}
10-13-17-BC-12-48   Media disconnected
22-B3-C5-30-76-78   \Device\Tcpip_{213E8D2A-1DBE-4240-8301-BE6F3EACAF9D}
00-05-2A-3C-78-00   \Device\Tcpip_{F01E3FC2-A5A1-6940-D1A1-C7521AEC4296}
2C-23-45-14-23-AD   Media disconnected
C:\>
```

For more details information visit here - [get-mac-address-command-line](https://www.windows-commandline.com/get-mac-address-command-line/)

For getting only mac-address, you can do something like

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=," %a in (`getmac /fo csv /v ^| find "Local Area Connection"`) do set MAC=%~a
```

Follow here - [get only the Ethernet MAC address](https://superuser.com/questions/892700/is-there-a-way-to-get-only-the-ethernet-mac-address-via-command-prompt-in-window/892843)

Comment: In linux, I filter the result and get only the macaddress. Is there any way to get only the macaddress by modifying the ipconfig /all

Comment: @Prem Follow http://superuser.com/questions/892700/is-there-a-way-to-get-only-the-ethernet-mac-address-via-command-prompt-in-window/892843 post it seems to have what you exactly want.

Answer (score 1):

To show macadresses

```
for /F "delims=: tokens=2" %a IN ('netsh lan show interfaces^|findstr /C:"Physical address"') do @echo %a
```

if you use that in  batch file, you need double the %.

```
for /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%a IN ('netsh lan show interfaces^|findstr /C:"Physical address"') do @echo %%a
```

You can do same with ipconfig, but machine can have virtual\tunnel interfaces, and ipconfig will show them, which may result in extra zeroed lines.

```
for /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%a IN ('ipconfig /all^|findstr /C:"Physical address"') do @echo %%a
```

To look for you MAC, just change argument of findstr